# asp page request authentication when accessing through ip

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7

I have a webserver running iis7. It works fine when i access through the server name for example; `http://myservername`, I can get to the page fine, which requires authentication by the way. However, when I try to access the page for example at `http://10.10.1.14` I get required to login. The server and the machine I am trying to access it are both on the same domain. For some reason it authenticates fine when I access it through the name but not the ip. Does anyone have any ideas what could be going on?

Thanks,

Comment: What does 'I get access for authentication' mean. What kind of authentication are you using?

Comment: kerberos, also my sql server on the same machine can only be accessed through the server name and not the ip.